# not able to call factory at controller

Tags: angularjs

I have created a factory named paging that will return numbers for pagination.

```
expenseApp.factory('paging', function() {
  this.pages = function(min, max, step) {
    if (max <= 5) {
      min = 1;
    }
    if (max > 5) {
      min = max - 3;
    }
    step = step || 1;
    var input = [];
    for (var i = min; i <= max; i += step)
      input.push(i);
    return input;
  };
```

I want to call this factory in my controller

```
 expenseApp.controller('expenseController', function($scope, $http, paging) {
    $scope.range = function() {
      $scope.answer = paging.range(0, 10, 1);
    }
  });
```

but this code is not working.
I tried it [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/OkBYOJccXx26jaRGAf7J?p=preview)

```js
var expenseApp = angular.module('expenseApp', []);
expenseApp.factory('paging', function() {
  this.pages = function(min, max, step) {
    if (max <= 5) {
      min = 1;
    }
    if (max > 5) {
      min = max - 3;
    }
    step = step || 1;
    var input = [];
    for (var i = min; i <= max; i += step)
      input.push(i);
    return input;
  };
  expenseApp.controller('expenseController', function($scope, $http, paging) {
    $scope.pages = function() {
      $scope.answer = paging.range(0, 10,1);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="MyApp.js"></script>
  <script src="MyCtrl.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="expenseApp" ng-controller="expenseController">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <ul class="pagination">
      <li ng-repeat="a in pages">
        <a ng-click="pagination(a)">{{a}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: paging.range???

Comment: Don't use the minified version of angular, so that you get readable error message. Once you've read the error message in the console, relaize that MYApp.js and MyApp.js are different file names. Then keep reading the next error message, and realize you've defined your controller from inside your factory definition. In short, debug and fix your code.

Comment: @slacker plese see the code updated

Comment: Not running....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var expenseApp = angular.module('expenseApp', []);
expenseApp.factory('paging', function() {
  return {
    pages: function(min, max, step) {
      if (max <= 5) {
        min = 1;
      }
      if (max > 5) {
        min = max - 3;
      }
      step = step || 1;
      var input = [];
      for (var i = min; i <= max; i += step)
        input.push(i);
      return input;
    }
  }
});

expenseApp.controller('expenseController', ['$scope', '$http', 'paging', function($scope, $http, paging) {
  $scope.pages = function() {
    $scope.answer = paging.pages(0, 10, 1);
  }
  $scope.pages();
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="expenseApp" ng-controller="expenseController">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <ul class="pagination">
      <li ng-repeat="a in answer">
        <a ng-click="pagination(a)">{{a}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Kindly check this snippet.

Changes I made:

**index.html**

```
<script src="MYApp.js"></script>

<ul class="pagination">
      <li ng-repeat="a in answer">
        <a ng-click="pagination(a)">{{a}}</a>
      </li>
</ul>
```

**MyCtrl.js**

```
expenseApp.factory('paging', function() {
  return {
    pages: function(min, max, step) {
      if (max <= 5) {
      min = 1;
    }
    if (max > 5) {
      min = max - 3;
    }
    step = step || 1;
    var input = [];
    for (var i = min; i <= max; i += step)
      input.push(i);
    return input;
    }
  }
});

expenseApp.controller('expenseController', ['$scope','$http', 'paging', function($scope, $http, paging) {
  $scope.pages = function() {
    console.log(paging)
    $scope.answer = paging.pages(0, 10,1);
  }
  $scope.pages();
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are getting error

`Error: [$injector:undef] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$injector/undef?p0=paging(…)`

Which means that your factory is not returning any values. So, to resolve this you can use this code in your factory

```
expenseApp.factory('paging', function() {
  var paging = {};
  var range = function(min, max, step) {
    if (max <= 5) {
      min = 1;
    }
    if (max > 5) {
      min = max - 3;
    }
    step = step || 1;
    var input = [];
    for (var i = min; i <= max; i += step)
      input.push(i);
    return input;
  };
  paging.range = range;
  return paging;
});
```

Notice that `var paging = {};` is a JSON object that will hold all the functionality provided by this factory like `range` so `paging.range = range;` will add a factory method `range` to the `range` key of the `paging` object. Then finally this object is returned from the service.

Now whenever you use the factory `paging`, then it is similar to using the JSON object `paging`. Thus, access `paging.range(0, 10,1)` will now invoke the factory method.

Your plunkr also does not work so here is the link to the working [PLUNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/EhbHLWwjwqUnfbJqkMSp?p=preview)

Comment: Code is not returing any value it should print 10 times as specified in repeat